# Filtered Data from Fusion Table in another FT infowindow using the FT UI

Tags: google-fusion-tables

Is it possible to embed an iframe with filtered data coming from a FT?
I have two Fusion Tables, one Parent and one Child.
They have a matching ID column.
What I need to do is to be able to show filtered data from Child Table into every infowindow of the Parent Table according to their matching ID column (sort of one-to-many connection).

Building on the link generated from the Child FT UI, I could generate a unique "filtering" link utilizing the matching ID column of the Parent Table inside the Custom Card panel.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible, but not with a template, because `<iframe/>`'s will be removed.

Modify the infoWindowHtml-property of the [`FusionTablesMouseEvent`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#FusionTablesMouseEvent)

```
google.maps.event.addListener(layer,'click',function(e){

  e.infoWindowHtml+=
    '<iframe width="100%" src="https://www.google.com/fusiontables/embedviz?'+
    'viz=CARD&amp;q=select+*+from+childTableId+where+ID+%3D+'+
    e.row.ID.value+'&cpr=1"></iframe>';

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was looking for a way to do this inside the Fusion Tables GUI modifying a template.

Comment: as I said, iframes will be removed.